# How to retrieve records from a table based on many to many relationship using eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have Three Models: Nationality, Nationality_Opportunity, Opportunity.

The Tables :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   nationalities   |  nationality_opportunities   |   opportunities
--------------------------------------------------------------------
        id                    nationality_id             id
        name                  opportunity_id             name
```

In Opportunity Model:

```
 public function nationalities(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Nationality::class,'nationality_opportunities','opportunity_id','nationality_id');
    }
```

In Nationality Model:

```
 public function opportunities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Opportunity::class,'nationality_opportunities','opportunity_id','nationality_id');

    }
```

-What do I want to do ?

I want to retrieve the opportunities records based on their selected nationalities which are sent as an array of ids through the request, so I want to check these ids in the pivot table in order to get their related opportunities records and display them in a Vue js component.

Scope Filter in Opportunity Model:

```
    public function scopeWithFilters($query)
    {
        return $query->when(count(request()->input('categories', [])), function ($query) {

            $query->whereIn('opp_cat_id', request()->input('categories'));

        })->when(count(request()->input('nationalities',[])),function ($query){

            $query->whereIn('nationalities.nationality_id', request()->input('nationalities'));

        });
    }
```

The parameter: nationalities = [1,2,3,5] .

Properties function in api controller:

```
 public function opportunities()
    {
        $opportunities = Opportunity::withFilters()->get();

        return PublicOpportunityResource::collection($opportunities);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Query is correct but you need to change the way you return the day please follow

```
$nationalities = [1,2,3,5]; //for temperory ids you can change it
$data= Nationality::with('opportunities')->whereIn('id', $nationalities)->get();

//return it as below
return response()->json($nationalities);
```

Comment: Bro I'm using this query for filtering opportunities, I'm trying to filter opportunities according to their related nationality ids and I want to search for those nationlity ids (coming from the request) in NationaltyOpportunity related pivot not directly querying those nationalities from Nationality Model. I hope you get my idea and I didn't confuse you. @Abdul Hakeem

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fetch opportunities with the code below

```
$nationalities = Nationality::with('opportunities')->whereIn('id', request()->input('nationalities'))->get();
```

And then you can access the opportunities by iterating over `$nationalities` or for the first row you can use `$nationalities->first()->opportunities`, not sure why you're using when in the callback function.

As per the edit you can make this query for your desired result

```
$nationalities = request()->input('nationalities');

$opportunities = Opportunity::with(['nationalities' => fn($q) => $q->whereIn('nationality_id', $nationalities)])->get();
```

Comment: Your answer is great. It'd be easy if I'm working in laravel balde , but what if I'm working with vue js and displaying these data in a vue js component and use this query for data filtering ?
Sorry. I didn't mention that at the beginning so I edited my question.
@Ashu

Comment: I have not worked with vue yet, but for react since we need the variable in javascript, we used https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer  package to turn those collections into json and use them in our components

Comment: Bro I'm using this query for filtering opportunities, I'm trying to filter opportunities according to their related nationality ids and I want to search for those nationlity ids (coming from the request) in NationaltyOpportunity related pivot not directly querying those nationalities from Nationality Model. I hope you get my idea and I didn't confuse you.

Comment: The query will fetch opportunities for that nationality ids only that are in the request

Comment: I'm sorry man. You're right. It turned out that my problem is in another function. I have updated the question. Can you see it please?

Comment: Not quite sure about the edited answer, can you give it a shot?

Comment: It gave me all the opportunities.They were not filtered.